# Block UI not working for blocking the div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, blockui, jquery-blockui

I am trying to block a particular div (div with id "blockit") on clicking a button (button with id "Button1"), for that I am using block UI plugin. But I am unable to block the div on button click. Here is my code

```
<script src="jQuery 1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="blockui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $('div.blockit').block({

                    message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
                    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }


                });
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
            });
        });

    </script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

        </div>
        <div id="blockit" style="width: 200px; height=200px;"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Please tell me where I am making mistake.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of specifying `blockit` as an `id` you have given it as `class` in jquery. Try this

```
       $('div#blockit').block({.....})
```

Comment: Its working now.. but now the problem is that the block element is just blinking and disappearing within a second. I want it to be stable for 2000ms

Comment: oh i got it my asp button causing page post back thats why it was not persisting... now its working all correct. but now the problem is that the time is not working and the div is blocking permanently

Answer (score 1):

For even easier and faster selector, because jQuery's `Sizzle` engine is optimized to use `ID` selectors, do the following:

```
$('#blockit').block({
    message: '<h1>Processing</h1>',
    css: { border: '3px solid #a00' }
});
```

The selector you had previously was `$('div.blockit')`, which will traverse the entire DOM and find all `DIV` elements before looking for one with the `ID` of `blockit`.

Comment: Its working now.. but now the problem is that the block element is just blinking and disappearing within a second. I want it to be stable for 2000ms

Comment: oh i got it my asp button causing page post back thats why it was not persisting... now its working all correct. but now the problem is that the time is not working and the div is blocking permanently